# Shifting form ASP.NET Core 3 to ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am following a [tutorial](https://codewithmukesh.com/blog/user-management-in-aspnet-core-mvc/) for learning ASP.NET CORE MVC. The tutorial is ASP.NET Core 5 based, whereas I am using ASP.NET Core 6.

I have already made a startup.cs file using [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cuOKV_0b-JI), but now I need to use the program.cs file as it was earlier (in ASP.NET Core 5).
How can I change the program.cs file to make it like the one in the ASP.NET Core 5, or is there another way to use the code?

The code I want to implement in program.cs is:

```
using system;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using LIBRARY.Data;
using LIBRARY.Models;
using LIBRARY;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Library.MVC
{
    public class Program
    {
        public async static Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            var host = CreateHostBuilder(args).Build();
            using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
            {
                var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
                var loggerFactory = services.GetRequiredService<ILoggerFactory>();
                try
                {
                    var context = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();
                    var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
                    var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
                    await ContextSeed.SeedRolesAsync(userManager, roleManager);
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    var logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<Program>();
                    logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred seeding the DB.");
                }
            }
            host.Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                });
    }
}
```

My startu.cs file is:

```
using LIBRARY.Data;
using LIBRARY.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using System.Configuration;

namespace LIBRARY
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; set; }
        public static WebApplication InitializeApp(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
            ConfigureServices(builder);
            var app = builder.Build();
            Configure(app);
            return app;
        }

        //



        //

        private static void ConfigureServices(WebApplicationBuilder builder)
        {
            //var connectionString = builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
            //builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            //    options.UseSqlServer(connectionString));
            //builder.Services.AddDatabaseDeveloperPageExceptionFilter();

            //builder.Services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>(options => options.SignIn.RequireConfirmedAccount = true)
            //    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
            //builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

            builder.Services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options => { options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")); });
            builder.Services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                    .AddDefaultUI()
                    .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
            builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

        }

        private static void Configure(WebApplication app)
        {
            if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseMigrationsEndPoint();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.MapControllerRoute(
                name: "default",
                pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
            app.MapRazorPages();

        }
    }
}
```

And when I put program.cs code in the program.cs file and run it.
It gives the following exception:

[image]

What the issue is and how I can solve it?

Comment: Hello Moaz Haroon, You forgot to add the await keyword before the async keyword.

Comment: Please be clear which versions of ASP.NET you are using - ASP.NET MVC 5 is definitely not the same as ASP.NET CORE 5 MVC!

Comment: Hi, @Moaz Haroon, I checked the tutorial you provided, This code is just for seeding data into database, There are many methods about how to seed data in .Net 6, You don't need to change your project structure because of this. If you need a method about how to seed data in .net 6, I can provide one.

Comment: Kindly provide one. @XinranShen

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to change a little code in your project instead of changing your project structure, Please refer this simple demo.

seeder method:

```
public static class ContextSeed
{
    public static async Task SeedRolesAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager, RoleManager<IdentityRole> roleManager)
    {
        //Seed Roles
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.SuperAdmin.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.Admin.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.Moderator.ToString()));
        await roleManager.CreateAsync(new IdentityRole(Enums.Roles.Basic.ToString()));
    }
}
```

Then in your program.cs

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
//.......................

var app = builder.Build();

await Configure(app);

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
//other middleware......
app.Run();


static async Task Configure(WebApplication host)
{
    using var scope = host.Services.CreateScope();
    var services = scope.ServiceProvider;

    try
    {
        var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();          

        var userManager = services.GetRequiredService<UserManager<ApplicationUser>>();
        var roleManager = services.GetRequiredService<RoleManager<IdentityRole>>();
        await ContextSeed.SeedRolesAsync(userManager, roleManager);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        //Log some error
        throw;
    }
}
```

Now, When you run your project, It will seed data into your database.

[image]

Comment: HI @Moaz Haroon, Can this method help you solve the isssue？

Comment: no, it did not help me solve the issue. Now I have another issue at

Comment: var dbContext = services.GetRequiredService<ApplicationDbContext>();

Comment: System.InvalidOperationException: 'No service for type 'LIBRARY.Data.ApplicationDbContext' has been registered.'

Comment: Is there a way I can contact you? I would like to explain what issues I am facing fully.

Comment: can you provide your current program.cs?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1CoWh74vwjstVIfJztwRoEuQmWGsceiR7/view?usp=drive_web

Here is my complete project file. Let me know if you can help me.

Comment: I check the file you provided, Please restore the original project structure (don't use `startup.cs`, just `program.cs` )  and add the code I provided above

Comment: In the "adding custom fields to identity user" section. I am supposed to change ConfigureServices function. How do I do that part without making startup.cs file?

Comment: I have solved this issue. By remaking the program.cs file. Thank you @Xinran Shen.

Answer (score 0):

Add a method

```
Public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder, IWebHostingEnvironment){
// your logic goes here
}
```

Its a mandatory for ASP apps.

Comment: Your link is outdated [aspnetcore-3.0] and not relevant for the version asked. Please edit your answer to the asked version

Comment: This was *never* mandatory. Even `Startup` wasn't mandatory. It's a convenience class with methods used to configure middleware like configuration and DI. You can configure each middleware separately if you want to.

Comment: Okay, I will update my question. But can you please elaborate on it a bit more? Where should I make the configure function, and what logic should I put into it? If u can tell me from my code what part I should put in configure? I am new to C# and ASP.NET.